# How do I create survey weights without sampling design data?

Tags: survey, survey-weights

Suppose I have a survey for which data was collected conveniently, but there aren't weights present.

The data set does have features like demographic data (e.g. age, gender, urban/rural location, education level), but it doesn't have weights of any kind.

I also have population demographics; e.g. the total population and proportions of education distribution in the population, as well as gender and living distributions.

How can I create weights from scratch?

Comment: https://bookdown.org/jespasareig/Book_How_to_weight_a_survey/calibration.html